# QSqlQuery не помещён в допустимую запись

Tags: sql, qt

ловлю такую ошибку

```
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
```

Вот сам код:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    // считываем бар код (переводим в дабл)
    // считываем базу данных
    // находим похожесть
    // выводим всю строку в базе данных
    // если нету такой похожести то выводим надпить "мой зад горит"
    QString inputText = ui->lineEdit->text();
    qDebug() << "inputText :" << inputText;
    double zapros = inputText.toDouble();

    // считываем данные из базы
    QSqlQuery query;

    if(!query.exec("SELECT * FROM " TABLE ";")){
        qDebug() << "Unable to execute query - exiting";
    }

    QSqlRecord rec = query.record();

    double BarCode;
    QString Name;
    QDate Date;

    bool tex_per=false;
    while(query.next()){
        BarCode = query.value(rec.indexOf("BarCode")).toDouble();
        qDebug() << "BarCode :" <<BarCode;
        if(BarCode == zapros){
            Name = query.value(rec.indexOf("Message")).toString();
            Date = query.value(rec.indexOf("Date")).toDate();
            qDebug()<<"|"<<BarCode<<"|"<<Name<<"|"<<Date<<"|";
            tex_per = true;
        }
    }
    if(tex_per==false){
        qDebug()<<"Такой штрих-код в базе данных не имеется";
    }
}
```

А вот вывод :

```
inputText : "1231321"
BarCode : 9.0238e+12
BarCode : 4.69043e+12
BarCode : 4.00476e+12
Такой штрих-код в базе данных не имеется

inputText : "4690432003609"
BarCode : 9.0238e+12
BarCode : 4.69043e+12
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
| 4.69043e+12 | "" | QDate("2017-08-12") |
BarCode : 4.00476e+12

inputText : "4004764390564"
BarCode : 9.0238e+12
BarCode : 4.69043e+12
BarCode : 4.00476e+12
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
| 4.00476e+12 | "" | QDate("2018-03-25") |
```

Как видим она(программа) ликвидные данные мне достаёт, но при этом почему то **не выдаёт позицию под названием "имя"** которая лежит в формате QString. Именно в этом и проблемма и менно на неё программа выдает `QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record`

В базе данных это `VARCHAR(255)` вставляеться в базу данных с помощью такой строки

```
query.bindValue(":Message",         data[1].toString());
```

Также почитал [этот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000123/qsqlquery-not-positioned-on-a-valid-record), по мне это не совсем мой вопрос.

вот картинка экрана:
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотри нормальное имя поля в базе... если драйвер БД говорит, что поля `Message` нет, то я доверяю драйверу... можешь даже просмотреть через API Qt: `for(int i=0; i++; i<rec.count()) { qDebug() << rec.fieldName(i); }`

Comment: @Fat-Zer Спасибо заработало. Можете оформить в виде ответа ?? (а я дополню выводом и снимками экрана)

Comment: оформляй.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fat-Zer дал ответ.

Надо было проверить есть ли такое поле "Message" в БД, *как и оказалось, нет :3*

эта строчка выдала мне все поля базы данных :

```
for(int i=0;i<rec.count();i++) { qDebug()<<"rec.fieldName("<<i<<"):"<<rec.fieldName(i); }
```

вот её вывод

```
rec.fieldName( 0 ): "id"
rec.fieldName( 1 ): "BarCode"
rec.fieldName( 2 ): "Name"
rec.fieldName( 3 ): "Date"
```

вот весь код :

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    // считываем бар код (переводим в дабл)
    // считываем базу данных
    // находим похожесть
    // выводим всю строку в базе данных
    // если нету такой похожести то выводим надпить "мой зад горит"
    QString inputText = ui->lineEdit->text();
    qDebug() << "inputText :" << inputText;
    double zapros = inputText.toDouble();

    // считываем данные из базы
    QSqlQuery query;

    if(!query.exec("SELECT * FROM " TABLE ";")){
        qDebug() << "Unable to execute query - exiting";
    }

    QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
    for(int i=0;i<rec.count();i++) { qDebug()<<"rec.fieldName("<<i<<"):"<<rec.fieldName(i); }

    double BarCode;
    QString Name;
    QDate Date;

    bool tex_per=false;
    while(query.next()){
        BarCode = query.value(rec.indexOf("BarCode")).toDouble();
        qDebug() << "BarCode :" <<BarCode;
        if(BarCode == zapros){
             Name = query.value(rec.indexOf("Name")).toString(); // вот тут теперь name
            Date = query.value(rec.indexOf("Date")).toDate();
            qDebug()<<"|"<<BarCode<<"|"<<Name<<"|"<<Date<<"|";
            tex_per = true;
        }
    }
    if(tex_per==false){
        qDebug()<<"Такой штрих-код в базе данных не имеется";
    }
 }
```

Вот вывод :

```
inputText : "4690432003609"
rec.fieldName( 0 ): "id"
rec.fieldName( 1 ): "BarCode"
rec.fieldName( 2 ): "Name"
rec.fieldName( 3 ): "Date"
BarCode : 9.0238e+12
BarCode : 4.69043e+12
| 4.69043e+12 | "Корректирующая жидкость" | QDate("2017-08-12") |
```